# SSIS how to set milliseconds to be zero?

Tags: datetime, ssis, milliseconds

I need to set fractional seconds of timestamp value to be zero.

E.g. Set "2012-11-10 14:57:43.147" to be "2012-11-10 14:57:43.000"

How could I do this in SSIS expression? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a proof of concept if you'd even want to set seconds to 00:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,27)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)"2012-11-10 14:57:43.147",1,16)+":00")
```

Similarly, for the eradication of milliseconds, take the first 19 characters:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,27)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)"2012-11-10 14:57:43.147",1,19)
```

Comment: So sorry I was trying to empty all my questions... I just realized this one is not removable so I accept the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`; you should try `DT_DBTIME` since it won't store milliseconds.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sqlintegrationservices/thread/57022d9b-c34a-47e8-bfee-d3489bd0a2db)